# All items of EditableText being handled as one

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have implemented the EditableText according to this post: https://www.polpiella.dev/swiftui-editable-list-text-items

```
struct EditableText: View {
    @Binding var text: String

    @State private var temporaryText: String
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        self._text = text
        self.temporaryText =    text.wrappedValue
     }

     var body: some View {
         TextField("", text: $temporaryText, onCommit: { text = temporaryText })
         .focused($isFocused, equals: true)
         .onTapGesture { isFocused = true }

     }
}
```

The behaviour is now correct in the sense that the keyboard does not close every time a character is typed.
However the problem for me is I am using this in a
ForEach inside of a List.

```
List { ForEach(sample array, id: ./self) { EditableText("Placeholder text", text: $0) } }
```

And everytime I tap on the button to create a new item, it gets initialised with the previous text rather than the placeholder text. And every time I edit the text of any item, all items get updated.

The expected behaviour is that I should be able to add new items with placeholder text and updating one item should not affect the other items.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Without any code it's pretty difficult to work out why this is happening. Please could you add some code to your question.

Comment: It’s expected if they are all sharing the same variables.

Comment: @Fogmeister yes I have added the code in the post now. After this I am simply using this in my Foraeach in my List.

Comment: `init` of `EditablText` take only one argument then this line:
`EditableText("Placeholder text", text: $0)` produce the compilation error:
`Extra argument in call`